# npm scripts: is there a cross platform conditional statement?

Tags: npm, cross-platform

I'm attempting to move an npm package over from being `*nix` dependent to being cross platform.  I have the following scripts entry in the `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist/ && tsc",
    // other entries
    "prepublish": "if [ ! $SKIP_PREPUBLISH ]; then npm run build; fi"
  },
```

I want to take the `if [ ! $SKIP_PREPUBLISH ]; then npm run build; fi` and make that cross platform.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score -1):

Starting from npm `5.1.0` you can change the script shell.

I placed this line in the `.npmrc` file and it works:

`script-shell = C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe`

You can also run this command:

`npm config set --userconfig script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"`